# Microsoft SQL 2012 Date differece based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of computers with columns including "Date Purchased" and "Warranty Expires." I would like for each computer (row) to take its date value in "Date Purchased" add 4 years and place the result in the "Warranty Expires" column. I'd also like this to automatically happen when I create a new computer and enter its Date Purchased if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Drop the column and make it computed:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName DROP COLUMN WarrantyExpires;

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName ADD WarrantyExpires
  AS CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(YEAR, 4, DatePurchased));
```

Or better yet, don't even store this. Since it's the same for every row (assuming you don't have warranties that aren't 4 years), just perform the calculation at runtime.

If it's not the same for every row, or if a customer can (now or later) extend their warranty, then a computed column is not the way to go. Instead:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName ADD WarrantyExpires DATE;
```

And then an `INSTEAD OF` trigger perhaps to populate it depending on the value provided by the insert (which you would use to override) or four years from the purchase date (if no value for expiration date was supplied). So:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.FixWarrantyDate
ON dbo.TableName
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.TableName(OrderID, /* other cols, */ DatePurchased, WarrantyExpires)
    SELECT OrderID, /* other cols, */ COALESCE(DatePurchased,GETDATE()),
      COALESCE(WarrantyExpires,DATEADD(YEAR,4,COALESCE(DatePurchased,GETDATE())))
    FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

So now your base insert could look like this for the default case:

```
INSERT dbo.TableName(OrderID, DatePurchased, WarrantyExpires)
  SELECT 1, GETDATE(), NULL;

-- or

INSERT dbo.TableName(OrderID, DatePurchased)
  SELECT 2, GETDATE();

-- or even:

INSERT dbo.TableName(OrderID) SELECT 3;
```

And if someone buys an extended warranty, you could override that (or update it later manually):

```
INSERT dbo.TableName(OrderID, DatePurchased, WarrantyExpires)
  SELECT 4, GETDATE(), DATEADD(YEAR, 5, GETDATE());
```

Resulting data in table after these four inserts:

```
OrderID   DatePurchased   WarrantyExpires
-------   -------------   ---------------
1         2013-10-25      2017-10-25
2         2013-10-25      2017-10-25
3         2013-10-25      2017-10-25
4         2013-10-25      2018-10-25
```

Now I feel I should also explain why I prefer `INSTEAD OF` triggers. While they do require you to re-write the insert statement, which after triggers do not, the benefits they add:

- Even after you've processed your business logic, you can still perform the insert (and update that an after trigger typically handles) in one single statement. This is much friendlier to the log.
- If you have business logic in your trigger that might rollback the transaction, it is much better to do so in an `INSTEAD OF` trigger. Instead of writing the row, affecting the log, possibly causing a page split, then deleting the row, affecting the log, and adding ghosted rows that need to be later cleaned up, you simply bail out and not perform the insert at all.

Comment: Or have a computed column :)

Comment: @Schalk isn't that what my answer suggests?